# Porting Android's DownloadManager to older versions like 2.2

Tags: android

Is there a way to port DownloadManager to older android versions?

Comment: My initial search lead me here, Just for the record, someone has now seem to have ported it at, https://github.com/JiboStore/DownloadProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to port DownloadManager to older android versions?

Not in any conventional sense.

In principle, you could grab the AOSP app that supplies the Downloads app and the Download provider, and try to backport that to run on older versions of Android.

However, `DownloadManager` itself is a system service, and that cannot be backported except by modifying the framework. You could attempt to create some sort of `DownloadManager` workalike that communicates with the Download provider, but it would not be `DownloadManager` itself.

And, how readily any of this can be backported, I cannot say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way - same as with any other software. Get source code and port.